# Apache Nifi - move a top-level element into children (JSON/XML)

Tags: apache-nifi

New to Apache Nifi and trying to process an XML that looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<productCatalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <version>CHANNELS-VERSION-100</version>
    <channels>
        <channel>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Super Channel 1</name>
        </channel>
         <channel>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Super Channel 2</name>
        </channel>
    </channels>
 </productCatalog>
```

What I want, is to read the "version" element, then include it in the "channel" children when I process them further down the pipeline e.g. to produce something like this (in XML or JSON):

```
<processedChannel>
    <catalogVersion>CHANNELS-VERSION-100</catalogVersion>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Super Channel 2</name>
</processedChannel>
```

I've tried various permutations of XQuery, XMLSplit, UpdateAttribute to put the version in a flow attribute (not content),etc, but I cannot seem to make the "version" available for *all* the "channels" downstream.  I can either get a flow that only contains the version, or I can get the channels, but I cannot find a way to combine them.

This seems like it should be easy, but I cannot find an obvious solution.

My real use case has a really big XML file, so I am trying to avoid loading it all in one go - I split it as early as possible so I can stream the children more easily.  That's why I want to put the version onto the children if possible.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: In case it helps, I can get the version out of the XML into a flow-file attribute e.g. via XQuery, but then my flow-file content only contains the version in the "matched" output, and I can't bring the "matched" and "unmatched" streams back together. What I want is to get the version into an *attribute*, but still be able to pass the XML downstream in the *content* for further processing. Then I can pull the version from the attribute down into the content e.g. as JSON later on.

Comment: Did you set the Destination of XQuery to "flowfile attribute"? If so then the content should remain untouched and the attribute should be added. Then you can use SplitXml downstream and add your version back in. If for some reason the XQuery processor doesn't work that way, try EvaluateXPath instead.

Answer (score 2):

[ForkRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ForkRecord/index.html) should do what you want. From your desired output I think you'll want "extract" as the mode, but you could try both and see what you get for output. ForkRecord and the XML Reader/Writer are available as of NiFi 1.7.0.

Comment: Thanks, but ForkRecord seems to require an Avro schema for my XML, and I don't have one - I can't infer one either because it's too big.  I know the elements I'm interested in and the rest is irrelevant so I don't need a schema for the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

@mattyb:  Thanks for your suggestions.  ForkRecord looks really interesting, but doesn't fit with my current use case because it needs a schema.  But the EvaluateXPath and EvaluateXQuery options both seem to work now, even though I spent hours playing around with these previously.

Here's my flow now:

ListFile --> FetchFile --> Evaluate XPath (to get version as flow-file attribute) --> SplitXml --> etc - and now I have the version in my flow-file attributes for the downstream processing, which was what was wanted.

Not sure why it didn't work before, but thanks for prompting me to look at it again.